# Как сделать чтобы в случае пустого поля TextView1 его место занимало TextView2

Tags: android

То есть если userName пусто то на его место смещался messagetext

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="left"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="11.5dp"
    android:id="@+id/messagetext"
    android:gravity="top|left|center"/>
```

Comment: 2й текстбокс нужет только для отображения надписи вместо пустого 1го текстбокса?

Comment: 1) случай у нас есть userName и есть messagetext - все нормально каждый занимает свою строчку. 2) случай поле userName пустое и messagetext  есть Вот тут чтобы сверху не было пустого места от userName необходимо сместить messagetext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо задать этим полям id, после чего в коде, при установки текста в данные поля, определить, будет ли установлено в поле `userName` какой либо текст или нет, если нет, то установить свойство видимости для данного поля `GONE`. Код будет выглядеть примерно так

```
TextView userName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
TextView message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);

String userNameStr = null;
String messageStr = null;

//код по получению данных для полей

if(username == null){
    userName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    username.setText(userNameStr);
}
//остальной код
```

Ну или можно изначально в разметке установить видимость для данного поля `GONE`, а потом при установки значения в данное поле установить видимость `visible`

Comment: А с помощью разметки это никак нельзя сделать например с помощью width ?

Comment: Не знаю, я делаю так, как описал выше, если хотите, можете поэкспериментировать. На мой взгляд это довольно простой и понятный вариант, все равно же вы как то туда данные устанавливаете, вот и установите флаг видимости во время установки данных

Answer (score 0):

Есть специальный атрибут `android:hint`, в котором пишется текст будет отображаться, если текстбокс пустой

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="@string/myText"
    android:gravity="left"/>
```

**Update**

Если уж вам совсем хочется именно написать значение 2-го текстбокса, то можно просто применить:

```
TextView userName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
TextView message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
userName.setHint(message.getText());
```